# do i need to check expiration cache in drupal from cache_get?

Tags: 6, caching

I'm using drupal 6 and I've build table that is similar to cache ([hook_schema](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--install.php/function/hook_schema/6)) for using it with function [cache_get](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--cache.inc/function/cache_get/6)/[cache_set](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--cache.inc/function/cache_set/6). 
I just want to be sure how things should work in drupal.

1. To clean the table I'll need to use hook [hook_flush_caches()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_flush_caches/6) where I'll decide if i want to clear expire data or whole cache? hook_flush_caches is called on cron?
2. In case I'll need to check data expiration by second, I'll need to do manually after cache_get function ?

This is kinda confusing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is actually pretty simple.

For your implementation of `hook_flush_caches`, all you need to do is return an array containing the names of your cache tables, eg

```
function mymodule_flush_caches ()
{
  return array("cache_mymodule");
}
```

[drupal_flush_all_caches](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_flush_all_caches/6) and [cache_clear_all](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--cache.inc/function/cache_clear_all/6) take care of the rest.  `drupal_flush_all_caches` is called anytime you manually clear the cache (the perforamnce page, admin menu, drush, etc).  [system_cron](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.module/function/system_cron/6) does get called by cron, and also clears the cache tables, but does not do some of the other things that `drupal_flush_all_caches` does.

When you get something out of the cache with `cache_get`, expired items will have already been removed from the cache; you don't need to manually check expirations.  They will be handled automatically according to how you put them in the cache with `cache_set`.

That's it.

Comment: I missed "hook_flush_caches" :(
Thanks!